# Android, End of Content Scroll Animation, How To Disable?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

You know the little bubbles that appear when you attempt to scroll past the end of content?

[image]

How do I disable them for a given RecyclerView fling event?

Answer (score 1):

Put the `overScrollMode` attribute into your `RecyclerView` XML:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never"/>
```

or in your `recyclerView` code in your `.class`

```
recyclerView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```